# How to censor a word in a char array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, replace

How can I find a word in a char array and censor it with wildcard (*) characters?

I've tried to find the first occurrence of the word, but failed. I've tried this and it didn't work either. I'm a newbie and I've been trying this for 5 hours.

```
int main()  
{
    int w,q;
    char l,m;
    char *arr, *swear;
    int i,a,t,k,z;

    printf("Enter a word which is not allowed.");
    scanf("%s", swear);
    printf("Now enter a word.");
    scanf("%s", arr);

    for(a=0; swear[a]!='\0'; ++a); //finding length of swear
    for(t=0;arr[t]!='\0';t++);    // finding length of arr

    for(i=0,k=0;k<t & i<t;i++,k++)
    {
        arr[i]=l;
        swear[k]=m;
        if(strstr(swear,arr))
            arr[i]='*';
        else
            break;
    }

    for(z=0;z<t;z++)
    {
        printf("%c",arr[z]);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: This is not how comments work. Comments are there to explain why you are doing what you're doing and not what you're doing. Might aswell get used to explain why and not what.

Comment: Please: show more code, especially how is `arr` declared. Read about [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks I edited my answer

Comment: `scanf` needs a big enough buffer to store strings not a dangling pointer. Try something like `char arr[1024], swear[1024];` and to prevent `scanf` writing out of the buffer `scanf("%1024s"`, swear);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to overwrite all occurrences of a string with an equal length string composed of `'*'`. For that you need to iteratively get pointers to occurrences of the string and you also need its length to know how many `'*'` you have to use.

```
size_t swearLength = strlen(swear); // swear is assumed null-terminated
char *here = arr;
while ((here = strstr(here, swear)) {
    memset(here, '*', swearLength);
    here += swearLength;  // to avoid searching what's already censored
}
```

`strstr` will return null if it can't find `swear` so the loop will terminate

Comment: suggestion, after memset line, add: `here += swearLength;` No point rechecking that which you have just written.

Comment: Looks good to me, downvoter care to enlighten?

Comment: Same problem as the other answer: `strstr` is not a *word* function.

Comment: @RadLexus To be far, the OP's code doesn't do that, nor does he ask for it.

Comment: @Alnitak: "How can I find a *word* in a char array ..." That said, that task alone is worth a short doctoral dissertation – and has been asked many, many times before on SO. Looking at OP's code I concur it's by far not the main problem (even thought OP spent a whopping whole "5 hours" on it; I have *thought* about specific problems far longer than that).